# Setting default folder for openfile dialog

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog

I have a `OpenFileDialog` and I am trying to set the default folder. Initially I had it set to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"\\new_folder1"` and that worked well. However I changed it to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"\\new_folder2"` and it still pops up in new_folder1. When I debug it, the dialog's `InitialDirectory` is new_folder2. I deleted new_folder1, but the dialog still looks for it when it starts up. There are now no references anywhere in my code to new_folder1.

Any ideas as to what might be happening?

Edit: Here is the code where I set up my initial `OpenFileDialog`:

```
 OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
 dlg.Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml";
 String pathDefault = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"\\new_folder2";
 dlg.InitialDirectory = pathDefault;
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code where you set the property?

Comment: Also, it's best practice to use `Path.Combine` when concatenating two folders together.

Comment: And why are you using a double backslash? Just use `Path.Combine` to avoid making mistakes like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `@"\\...."`.  Either get rid of the @ or change the `\\` to `\`.

Or, try:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"new_folder2")
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. I still don't understand why it was searching for new_folder1, or why when the default was `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"\\new_folder1"` it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah that is strange - I don't know either.

Comment: Looks like `OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory` will accept an invalid path like _C:\Users\fred\Documents\\new_folder1_ (notice the double backslash). Either `OpenFileDialog` or the underlying common dialog is hiding the error that would occur on navigating to that directory. This would explain why the common dialog state doesn't change to the invalid directory.